# Queuing panorama rendering on Lightroom

Tags: lightroom, panorama, batch

I have a whole bunch of panoramas to render on Lightroom. The problem is that when I render one, my PC is dying and I can't really do much with it, much less continue using Lightroom to develop other pictures. I usually end up using my phone to do random stuff while waiting for the panorama to be made, and then I can use Lightroom again. As you can imagine, this is very frustrating.

Is there a way to queue all the panoramas rendering and launch them when it's convenient for me (i.e. when I will not use the computer)?

Note: this question would probably be the same for HDR rendering.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you are not alone with this problem. You can check [here](https://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/batch-hdr?topic-reply-list%5Bsettings%5D%5Bfilter_by%5D=all) and [here](https://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/queueing-panorama-hdr-based-on-smart-preview-for-final-rendering) about discussions/requests for such option. What you can try is to activate graphical processor to help with rendering the panorama. Also you can check those [recommendations from Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/kb/optimize-performance-lightroom.html) about Lightroom optimization

EDIT: According to [this document](https://helpx.adobe.com/bg/lightroom-classic/help/whats-new/2019-4.html) now is possible to run panoramas/HDR stitch in batch. Probably it is not what you want but at least IMHO is step in right direction

Answer (score -1):

Do them at night, while you are sleeping or at any other time you are not using your computer. use the free Microsoft’s **[PoweShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/)** to automate the whole process.

Comment: How might one do this with Powershell?

Comment: I can't do them at night, as I can't queue them. I would have to get up and prepare and launch the next one.

Comment: I use MacOs not windows and in Mac there're ways to do it using readily available tools like keyboard maestro, applescript an d python, in Windows using PowerShell you should be able to create a virtual queue to order Lightroom to fetch a new panorama as soon as the previous is done and written to the disk