# Automatically merge all HDR sequences in folder in Lightroom CC Classic

Tags: lightroom, hdr, bracketing

I've been shooting a lot of raw 3-exposure bracketed shots recently which I've been merging into HDR images in Lightroom Classic CC (Mac).

I find the process of selecting 3 images, going into the menu to select HDR, viewing the preview and then starting the merge for every sequence to be quite tedious.

I might shoot 20+ sequences in a day - a lot of the hiking I do is in areas with a mix of dark forests and bright snowy alpine areas so dynamic range is always a challenge. I use Nikon D5100 which won't let you turn on HDR when shooting raw.

I would like some mechanism of detecting all sequences (images shot within a couple seconds of each other) and merging them with HDR using the same settings (no anti-ghosting) and skipping the preview.

Is there a way to do this that I have overlooked? Or could you point me in the right direction to find a way to script this behaviour?

Comment: Check this answer (its about panoramas, but the facts remain): https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/106137/34947

Comment: You can combine images taken very close to each other into stacks using autostack: https://petapixel.com/2017/09/18/harnessing-power-auto-stacking-lightroom/ This will at least cut down on the remaining process.

Answer (score 1):

With the new version of Lightroom Classic you can automate some of the tasks. You need to stack the images for each HDR and then run the process for all of them. You can check [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/bg/lightroom-classic/help/whats-new/2019-4.html) for more information.